# Unusual ListView and Spinner issues with SQLDatabase

Tags: android, listview, database-connection, spinner

I haven't been able to figure this one out.

I have two activities, one with a listview, the other with a spinner. Both are supposed to be binding to the same data source. Both are using the same method for accessing the data. However, while the listview opens the database and fills the list just fine, the spinner crashes as soon as it hit my database helper open method.

Below is the StackTrace:

06-23 20:52:18.836: WARN/System.err(16420): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

com.enkadia.reelogistics_0621.ProjectActivity.fillProjectSpinner(ProjectActivity.java:46)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

com.enkadia.reelogistics_0621.ProjectActivity.onCreate(ProjectActivity.java:27)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow

(ActivityThread.java:2503)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState

(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
06-23 20:52:18.857: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.widget.TabHost

$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab

(TabHost.java:323)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab

(TabHost.java:213)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

com.enkadia.reelogistics_0621.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-23 20:52:18.866: WARN/System.err(16420):     at

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-23 20:52:18.876: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300

(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-23 20:52:18.876: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-23 20:52:18.876: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

(Handler.java:99)
06-23 20:52:18.876: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-23 20:52:18.876: WARN/System.err(16420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-23 20:52:18.887: WARN/System.err(16420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native

Method)
06-23 20:52:18.887: WARN/System.err(16420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:521)
06-23 20:52:18.887: WARN/System.err(16420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-23 20:52:18.887: WARN/System.err(16420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-23 20:52:18.887: WARN/System.err(16420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Face Palm**

Don't instantiate your database helper in one Activity and forget to do it in the other.
Things working much better now.